# Rmagick compress when filesize is bigger than X without write (upload to S3)

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, rmagick

I would like to compress an image when its size is bigger than an amount (i.e. 1000000 - 1MB). I see compress is used with write method in Image object. I have the image in memory and I don´t want to write it in my server but in an Amazon S3.

This code is working. It´s uploading the image to my s3 path, however I would like to include the filesize check and the compress:

```
photo = Magick::Image.read(mmkResourceImage.href).first           
s3 = AWS::S3.new      
bucket = s3.buckets[bucketName]            
obj = bucket.objects[key]    
obj.write(photo)
```

Please, let me know if there is another approach to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current size you can use [Magick::Image#to_blob](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick/Image#to_blob-instance_method) which will return a binary string. You can get the string's size with [String#bytesize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-bytesize). You can scale it down with [Magick::Image#scale!](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick/Image#scale!-instance_method).

Here is an example that would resize it by 75% until it was under a 1,000,000 bytes.

```
while photo.to_blob.bytesize > 1_000_000
  photo.scale!(0.75)
end
```

Here is an example that would reduce the quality instead

```
(0..100).step(5).reverse_each do |quality|
  blob = photo.to_blob { self.quality = quality }

  if blob.bytesize <= 1_000_000
    photo = Magick::Image.from_blob(blob).first
    break
  end  
end
```

Comment: I suspect continually scaling an image like that can lead to quality issues. The in memory size check looks good though.

Comment: Thanks! I meant to call that out. A feedback controller could improve the efficiency. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to predict the how much correction is needed. ImageMagick lowers the quality instead of dimensions with the `jpeg:extent` option. I still has to search for the right quality to produce the desired filesize. [Source](https://github.com/xushiwei/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/jpeg.c#L1959)

Comment: Hi, I don´t want to scale. The image is already properly scaled. I just need to compress.

Comment: I added another example this time reducing the quality to affect the compression ratio.

Comment: With Rmagic new update `blob = photo.to_blob { self.quality = quality }` will no longer work. Instead use `blob = photo.to_blob { |image| image.quality = quality }`